# Custom post types as sub menu pages and role capabilities issue

Tags: custom-post-types, user-roles, admin-menu, capabilities

I'm working on this:

- Create a menu entry in the admin panel name "Products"
- Have a dozen of custom post types, all as submenus items of my admin menu "Products" entry
- Allow a role to only show this, and not others custom post types.

The two first points are working very well, here is my code:

```php
class Product {
    private const POST_TYPES = array(...);

    public function __construct() {
        add_action('init', array($this, 'registerProductsPostTypes'));
        add_action('admin_menu', array($this, 'registerMenuProductPostType'));
    }

    public function registerMenuProductPostType(): void {
        add_menu_page(
            'Produits',
            'Produits',
            'products',
            'products',
            array($this, 'initProductsMenu'),
            'dashicons-products',
            '20'
        );
    }

    public function registerProductsPostTypes() {
        foreach (self::POSTS_TYPES as $postsType) {
            register_post_type($postsType['postType'], array(
                'labels' => array(
                    'name' => $postsType['label'],
                    'menu_name' => $postsType['menu'] ?? $postsType['label']
                ),
                'public' => true,
                'has_archive' => 'explorer/' . $postsType['slug'],
                'rewrite' => 'explorer/' . $postsType['slug'],
                'show_in_menu' => 'products',
                'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'),
                'taxonomies' => array(),
                'capability_type' => array('product', 'products'),
                'map_meta_cap' => true
            ));
        }        
    }
}
```

How you can see it, I added a capability `products` to my menu item to make it available to my custom role (see below) and a `capability_type` on all my post types to trigger them on the custom role too, with the `map_meta_cap` param.

Here is my role creation:

```php
add_role(self::ROLE_SLUG, self::ROLE_NAME); // (class constants are well defined)
$role = get_role(self::ROLE_SLUG);

$role->add_cap('read');

// To make the menu item displays and the list of post types on edit.php?post_type=xxx
$role->add_cap('products');

// Add all caps to allow full control of products post types
$role->add_cap('edit_product');
$role->add_cap('read_product');
$role->add_cap('create_product');
$role->add_cap('create_products');
$role->add_cap('delete_product');
$role->add_cap('edit_products');
$role->add_cap('edit_others_products');
$role->add_cap('read_private_products');
$role->add_cap('delete_products');
$role->add_cap('delete_private_products');
$role->add_cap('delete_published_products');
$role->add_cap('delete_others_products');
$role->add_cap('edit_private_products');
$role->add_cap('edit_published_products');
```

At this point, user with this custom role can access admin and display the whole post types on their `edit.php?post_type=xxx` page.

**Problem**: the user cannot create a new item on the `post-new.php?post_type=xxx` page. A "not allowed" WordPress error page appears.

I do not know if this can be a real WordPress bug, because:

- If I add the `edit_posts` capability to my custom role, the user can display the `post-new.php` page properly for my custom post type items
- or if I replace the `show_in_menu => 'products'` with `show_in_menu => true` to display all my post types at top first menu level items, this seems to be working too.

Maybe I'm doing something wrong, and if someone already face this kind of issue, he or she could be really helpful.

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding the problem or the exact question, but you will definitely need to add `edit_posts` capability to the custom role for the functionality you describe.  Is there a reason you do not wish to add that capability?

Comment: Don't want the user be able to edit posts or access things with this cap. And if I do my second point (move my cpts as top level pages), It's working. So I assume that `edit_posts` cap is not required.

Comment: Sooo, what's the question you need answered?

Comment: I've also run into this issue. To describe it a different way, when `show_in_menu` is `true`, custom capabilities seem to work as expected and the user with those capabilities is restricted to only that menu. However, when `show_in_menu` is a string, such as `products` or in my case `edit.php?post_type=contract`, the user cannot create new posts of that type. My feeling is that this is a WordPress bug as `show_in_menu: true` and `show_in_menu: 'products'` ought to behave the same.